# Renderer running two programs and high vertices/faces

Tags: three.js

I'm developing a little game in ThreeJs and have stumbled upon a problem I seem not to understand.

Im creating a game instance, after it I'm loading my enemies which are added to an array of enemies. Before I can do it i load my 3D objects with loader.load('assets/data/', callback()) and then create the enemies.

However there are two problems here. As soon as the callback is called my renderer show 2 programs running and the second problem is I'm having huge amount of vertices and faces on only 10 enemy meshes!

Is it that i must go back to blender and set the vertices/faces lower somehow or what am I doing wrong?

Just hint if you need more info!

[image]

Regards.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by 'my renderer show two programs running'  and how is it linked to the callback ? With 10 instances the vertices should not be a problem, unless you use too heavy textures or you have more than 2000 to 10000 vertices for each, depending the computer. However vertices don't create second program ! If you have good detailed enemies and use to face FPS drop, you can use less detailed ones at farther distances with the level of detail (`THREE.LOD()`).